# How to get outlook free busy schedule using microsoft-graph sdk php

Tags: php, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I am using microsoft-graph api sdk here is the url: [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)

I need to check if an user's appointment is available / busy in the outlook calendar.

I am trying using following code

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($this->getToken($calendar));
$data = [
        'Schedules' => 'useremail@gmail.com',
        'Start' => [
            'DateTime' => '2019-06-8T09:00:00+0530',
            'TimeZone' => 'Pacific Standard Time',
        ],
        'End' => [
            'DateTime' => '2019-06-9T09:00:00+0530',
            'TimeZone' => 'Pacific Standard Time',
        ],
        'availabilityViewInterval' => '30',
    ];

    $url = "/me/calendar/getschedule";
    $response = $graph->createRequest("POST", $url)
        ->attachBody($data)
        ->setReturnType(Model\ScheduleItem::class)
        ->execute();
```

I am getting following error : message: "Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getschedule` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:↵{
↵  "error": {
↵    "code": "RequestBodyRead",
↵    "message": "When trying to read a null collection parameter value i (truncated...)↵

I have also checked this microsoft docs details here is the url : [outlook-get-free-busy-schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule)

I did not found getschedule-api using php microsoft-graph sdk in documentation. I need to use php microsoft-graph api sdk.

kindly provide me any solution about this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not need to pass

```
setReturnType
```

Try using this :

```
$data = [
    'Schedules' => ['avniphadkar@gmail.com'],
    "StartTime" => (object)[
        "dateTime" => "2019-06-08T09:00:00",
        "timeZone" => "Pacific Standard Time"
    ],
    "EndTime" => (object)[
        "dateTime" => "2019-06-8T23:00:00",
        "timeZone" => "Pacific Standard Time"
    ],
    'availabilityViewInterval' => '30'
];


$url = "/me/calendar/getschedule";
$response = $graph->createRequest("POST", $url)
->attachBody($data)
->execute();

print_r($response)
```

;

Hope this'll help.